# How to convert time to deg or rad in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make clock on js. How to rotate hour hand depending on the time? I need to convert time in deg or rad? My code now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var img = new Image();
    var bee = new Image();
    var i = 40;
    img.src = "images/clock.jpg";


    img.onload = function(){
        bee.src = "images/bee.jpg";
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        ctx.drawImage(bee, 95, 90);

        setInterval(function(){
            i = i+1;
            ctx.save(); //saves the state of canvas
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear the canvas
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
            ctx.rotate(225*Math.PI/180);
            ctx.drawImage(bee, -85, -90);

            ctx.restore(); 

        }, 100);


    }
});
```

My clock sreen:
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHB3b.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math...

For minute hand

- 60 minutes is a full rotation
- A full rotation is 360 degrees or 2*pi
- Any fraction of 60 minutes is a fraction of 360 degrees or 2*pi
- i.e. 23 min is (23/60)*2*pi radians or (23/60)*360 degrees
- Add in seconds as 1/60 of a minute if you want a continuously moving minute hand

For hour hand

- 12 hours is a full rotation
- Add on minutes by figuring out that every minute is 1/60 of an hour
- Use the same rule as above to convert to degrees or radians